# HTML parsing by python, how to parse attribute that is unusual?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I got a question for HTML parsing using python.

I'm trying to get the attribute key and value to use if fomular in python.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <p dir="ltr" class="FM_title_0">Test Color</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is code that i am making as follow

```
with open("C:\\file") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
tag = soup.p
if tag['class'] == 'FM_title_0' :
    print('aaa')
```

but the result shows nothing. i figure out that tag['class'] is not able to read 'FM_title_0'. 
why does it not read 'FM_title_0' ??

additionally, when i run this code below

```
with open("C:\\file") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
tag = soup.p
print(tag['class'])
```

it shows ['FM_title_0']. but please look this one below

```
with open("C:\\file") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
tag = soup.p
print(tag['dir'])
```

this result shows ltr.

Is there any difference between [xxx] and xxx when read attribute's value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of tag['class'] is a list. It contains  list of all the classes the tag has. So you can use the **in** operator to compare. Check the code below for your reference

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("test.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
tag = soup.p
print tag['class']
if 'FM_title_0' in tag['class'] :
    print('aaa')
```

Comment: i got understood! Thanks have a great day.